# Opening many text files in Python and running the same code on all of them

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and my question is about running the same code on many txt files. I have almost 300 txt files, and I want to run a piece of code on all of them.  How do I open all of those files in one loop and get my output?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should post some code that shows what you're trying to do, and explain what problem you are having with that code. If you're using Python 3 you should take a look at the `pathlib` module.

Comment: @sara are all text files inside one folder?

Comment: yeah all of them are inside one folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all of the the files are found inside the same folder you can use os module.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("path-to-the-folder"):
    with open(os.path.join("path-to-the-folder",filename),"r") as file:
        content = file.read()
```

EDIT:
To write output to single file with name "output.txt"

```
import os 
with open("output.txt","w+") as outputfile:
    for filename in os.listdir("path-to-the-folder"):
        with open(os.path.join("path-to-the-folder",filename),"r") as file:
            content = file.read()
            outputfile.write(content)
```

Comment: What if all the files aren't in the same folder? What if "path-to-the-folder" contains subdirectories?

Comment: @Mitiku thanks now I want to run one code on all of the myfiles and get output in a txtfile , how can call my code for this aim?